# How are you supposed to flowtype redux thunk?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

What I'm currently doing is:

```
export type Action =
   { type: 'FOO' }
 | { type: 'BAR' }

export type Thunk = (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => Action | Thunk 

export type Dispatch = ReduxDispatch<Action> & (action: Thunk) => void
```

but if you dispatch directly on the `store`, that won't work without recreating `store`:

`export type Store = ReduxStore<State, Action>`

In general, my thunk solution seems to have other minor problems. Does anyone have a working library definition for `redux-thunk`? I can't find one anywhere.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The best example I've found so far are the ones used in Facebook's own F8 app [here](https://github.com/fbsamples/f8app/blob/master/js/actions/types.js).

It's pretty similar to yours:

```
export type Dispatch = (action: Action | ThunkAction | PromiseAction | Array<Action>) => any;
export type GetState = () => Object;
export type ThunkAction = (dispatch: Dispatch, getState: GetState) => any;
export type PromiseAction = Promise<Action>;
```

It's worked pretty well for me so far in my project, though I don't dispatch directly on the store anywhere.